# Django runserver_plus pyOpenSSL not installed error, although it is

Tags: python, django, pyopenssl

Linux Mint 19.3, Python 3.8 virtual environment.
So I try to run runserver_plus using ssl:

```
python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt
```

Then I get following error:

```
CommandError: Python OpenSSL Library is required to use runserver_plus with ssl support. Install via pip (pip install pyOpenSSL).
```

But the deal is that pyOpenSSL is already installed within my environment. Here is pip list output:

```
asgiref (3.5.2)
certifi (2022.9.24)
cffi (1.15.1)
charset-normalizer (2.1.1)
cryptography (38.0.3)
defusedxml (0.7.1)
Django (3.0.14)
django-extensions (2.2.5)
idna (3.4)
oauthlib (3.2.2)
Pillow (7.0.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
pycparser (2.21)
PyJWT (2.6.0)
pyOpenSSL (19.0.0)
python3-openid (3.2.0)
pytz (2022.6)
requests (2.28.1)
requests-oauthlib (1.3.1)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.16.0)
social-auth-app-django (3.1.0)
social-auth-core (4.3.0)
sqlparse (0.4.3)
urllib3 (1.26.12)
Werkzeug (0.16.0)
wheel (0.38.4)
```

Thanks in forward for any help!

I've tried to install different versions of pyOpenSSL, both erlier and later.  Unsuccessfully.

Runserver_plus starts successfully without additional parameters, but my point is to access virtual server securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the deal was in outdated pip. I thought that update pip via apt utility is enough, but it's not. Pip official site provides special script for update operation. After update via script is complete PyOpenSSL should be reinstalled. As the result runserver_plus must start correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Such issue can appear when you need to recompile cryptography with the correct openssl.

To do that you can check the cryptography [docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/).

```
$ pip uninstall pyopenssl
$ pip uninstall cryptography
$ env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography
$ pip install pyopenssl
$ python manage.py shell_plus
$ python manage.py runserver_plus --cert=foo.cert
```

Comment: env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pip install cryptography

Failed with:

Error: Invalid formula: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/vorbis-tools.rb
Error: Cannot tap homebrew/core: invalid syntax in tap!
Error: Failure while executing; `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.
bash: /usr/bin/env: Too long list of arguments

Comment: Thanks for link to cryptography docs! My problem was outdated pip. The trick is to update pip by running the special script instead of using apt utility.